# Excel 2010 vba not working in Excel 2012

Tags: vba, excel

I have vba code that creates a pivot table automatically from some data that is copied from another workbook to the current workbook. When I run it on my machine, it is fine. Another person has no problems, either, but one woman is getting an error about "Run-time error '5': Invalid procedure call or argument" and it highlights my code for

```
"ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
  "WorkRange", Version:=xlPivotTableVersion14).CreatePivotTable _
  TableDestination:=ActiveSheet.Cells(3,1), TableName:="PivotTable2", DefaultVersion _ 
  :=xlPivotTableVersion14
```

My code copies the new data sheet and renames it every time to "Call Data - Date Time" and creates a new pivot table on a new sheet every time, so I don't think it is the table name causing issues, especially since it runs fine for me. She is the only one having issues. Any ideas?

Here is all of the code:

```
Sub GeneratePivot()
'
' Macro11 Macro
'
    Dim myDate As Date, aDate
    myDate = Date + 7 - Weekday(Date)
    aDate = Format(myDate, "mm.dd.yyyy")

    Dim LValue As Date
    LValue = Now

    Range("A1").Select
    Range(Selection, ActiveCell.SpecialCells(xlLastCell)).Select

    ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="WorkRange", RefersTo:=Selection
    Range("C5").Select
    Application.Goto Reference:="WorkRange"
    Sheets.Add
    ActiveSheet.Name = "SummaryData " & Format(DateTime.Now, "MM.dd.yy hh.mm.ss")

    ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
        "WorkRange", Version:=xlPivotTableVersion14).CreatePivotTable _
        TableDestination:=ActiveSheet.Cells(3, 1), TableName:="PivotTable2", DefaultVersion _
        :=xlPivotTableVersion14
    ActiveSheet.Select
    Cells(3, 1).Select

    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2").PivotFields("Month")
        .Orientation = xlColumnField
        .Position = 1
    End With

    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2").PivotFields("Site/Location")
        .Orientation = xlRowField
        .Position = 1
    End With

    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2").PivotFields("Called Number")
        .Orientation = xlRowField
    End With

    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2").AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _
        "PivotTable2").PivotFields("Called Number"), "Count of Called Number", xlCount

    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2").PivotFields("Site/Location")
        .PivotItems("#N/A").Visible = False
    End With

    Columns("A:A").Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove

End Sub
```

So I updated the suspect lines to:

```
Dim PC As PivotCache
Dim pt As PivotTable

Set PC = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
        "WorkRange", Version:=xlPivotTableVersionCurrent)

Set pt = PTCache.CreatePivotTable _
        (TableDestination:=ActiveSheet.Cells(3, 1), _
        TableName:="PivotTable1", _
        DefaultVersion:=xlPivotTableVersionCurrent)

PC.CreatePivotTable TableDestination:=ActiveSheet.Cells(3, 1), TableName:="PivotTable1", DefaultVersion _ :=xlPivotTableVersionCurrent
```

And it failes on Set PC. I also tried xlPivotTableVersion15, but that failed, as well.

Comment: There's a lot going on in that line, so a good start might be to split it up into separate lines which first create the PivotCache and then create the PivotTable.

Comment: Is she opening the worksheet with macros enabled?  http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/excel-help/enable-or-disable-macros-in-office-files-HA010354316.aspx

Comment: @SQLDBA - she's getting a run-time error, so macros are enabled...

Comment: There's always checking for consistent Object Library References.

Comment: The saved pivot table data model was changed in Excel 2013. Excel 2013 also has new pivot table VBA functions not found in the older versions. If you need to support both old and current Excel versions you will either have to maintain two separate code branches with two separate "file formats". Excel 2010 can read some of the Excel 2013 pivot table data but upon saving produced completely unrecoverable binary garbage (user's data lost). Which **exactly** Excel **versions** do you have on your machine and on another person's machine?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is because of the version of the PivotTable namely this section:
 `Version:=xlPivotTableVersion14`
Version14 is for Excel 2010. I'm not sure what the version number is for 2012.
Try changing it to:
`DefaultVersion:=xlPivotTableVersionCurrent` and see if it runs.

Here is a list (taken from here: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.xlpivottableversionlist(v=office.15).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.xlpivottableversionlist%28v=office.15%29.aspx)) with the available versions.  I don't see Excel 2012 on there, so your mileage may vary:

xlPivotTableVersion2000 refers to  Excel 2000
   xlPivotTableVersion10 refers to Excel 2002
   xlPivotTableVersion11 refers to Excel 2003
   xlPivotTableVersion12 refers to Excel 2007
   xlPivotTableVersion14 refers to Excel 2010
   xlPivotTableVersion15 refers to Excel 2013
   xlPivotTableVersionCurrent refers to Provided only for backward compatibility